# Sorting linked list with multiple parameters

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm having a trouble with my school project. I was asked to use a linked list, I'm almost finish but then I got stuck in how do I sort my data by looking at the date

I want to display these data by sorting the date

I have searched everywhere and I still can't find how to sort a linked list multiple parameters
say these are the parameters:

```
struct Data { 
    int kode;           
    char variety[20];   
    int weight;             
    int date;       
    struct Data *next;  
} *headIn, *tempIn;
```

with a `main` function like this:

```
int menu;                               
int pointIn = 0;    
int amount = 0;             
void insert(int kode, char *variety, int weight, int date);
void userInput();
void printList(struct Data *tempIn);  

int main() { 
    headIn = NULL;
    int menu = 0; 

    do {   
        system ("cls");
        printf( " \n\nMAIN MENU :\n");
        printf( " 1. Input Product\n\n");
        printf( " 2. Print List\n\n");
        printf( " enter your choice (1 - 2) : "); 
        scanf("%d", &menu); 

        if (menu < 1 || menu > 2) {
            system("cls");
            printf ("your input is not available\n");
            getch();
        }
        switch (menu) { 
        case 1:
            userInput();
            break;
        case 2:
            printList(tempIn); 
            break;
        }
    }
    
    while (menu != 3);
    system("cls");
    printf ("============ Thankyou ============");

    return 0;
}
```

and then I apply this function so that the data is going to be a linked list:

```
void insert(int kode, char *variety, int weight, int date) {
    struct Data *dataIn = (struct Data *)malloc(sizeof(struct Data));
    dataIn->kode = kode;
    strcpy(dataIn->variety, variety);
    dataIn->weight = weight;
    dataIn->date = date;
    dataIn->next = NULL;
    
    if (headIn == NULL) {
        headIn = dataIn;
    } else {
        dataIn->next = headIn;
        headIn = dataIn;
    }
}
```

and then I have this 2 function for asking user's input and the other is for printing

```
void userInput() { 
    int code; 
    int weight;
    int date;
    amount = 0;
    char variety[5][20] = { "Fish", "Crab", "Squid", "Clam", "Lobster" };

    system ("cls");
    printf("Number of data you want to enter : "); scanf("%d", &amount);
    printf( "_________________________________________________________________\n");
    printf("\n Kode 0 = Fish \n kode 1 = Crab \n kode 2 = Squid \n kode 3 = Clam \n kode 4 = Lobster\n\t\t\t   ");
        
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {  
        printf("\n\nProduct-%d", pointIn + 1);
        printf("\n\tInput code\t : "); scanf(" %d", &code); 
        if (code < 0 || code > 4) { 
            printf ("this code product is not available\n");
            i--;
        } else {                
            printf("\tJenis\t\t : %s\n", variety[code]);
            printf("\tINPUT weight\t : "); scanf(" %d", &weight ); 
            printf("\tInput date (YYYYMMDD)\t : ");scanf(" %d", &date); 
            pointIn++;
            insert(code, variety[code], weight, date);
        }
    }
    getch();
}

void printList(struct Data *tempIn) {
    system ("cls");
    tempIn = headIn;
    
    //sort function here
    
    printf("*****  DATA PRODUCT ***** \n" );
    printf("|  DATE  |  CODE  |      NAME      |  WEIGHT | \n");
    
    while (tempIn != NULL) {
        printf("    %d        %d     %s          %d        \n", tempIn->date, tempIn->kode, tempIn->variety, tempIn->weight);
        tempIn = tempIn->next;
    }
    getch();
}
```

please help me I don't understand and I can't find any references, it's just this sorting part I'm stuck in.

Comment: Hey ! I don't see any thing related to the sorting here. Did you try something to sort it out ? Even with one parameter? If you did, add it here. :)

Comment: oh i forgot to mention it, i wan't to sort by using the date from the user's input

Comment: That isn't multi-parameter sorting. It is sorting based on *one* field of a structure. Doing that is no different than sorting a sequence of simple native values; the only difference is where that value comes from. It should also be made crystal clear in your post whether the attempt (which you did not show, but should) is intended to build the list as-sorted, or sort the list after the fact. The former is trivial; the latter can get complicated if done efficiently, especially for a linked list.

Comment: i have not yet to know how to sort this linked list, the only successfull attempt i've made was using an array type. do you know any learning reference on how to sort let's say i want to sort the date, then the order of other part of the structure also get changed.

example in array type, let's say i have data[1].number=2, data[1].name=fish ; data[2].number=1, data[2].name = crab. if i sort this using the number, i get 1. crab then 2. fish. but how to do this kind of sorting in linked list? all i see from youtube and internet, they only use 1 data in struct meanwhile i have 4 data

Comment: start with single element like int "kode"  datatype in the linked-list first and do the sorting algorithm. Increment to two parameters and so one until you cover all the Data elements

Answer (score 0):

In the `Insert` function, you must find the proper place to insert the node by iterating in the list past the nodes with a lesser date:

```
void insert(int kode, const char *variety, int weight, int date) {
    struct Data *dataIn = (struct Data *)malloc(sizeof(struct Data));
    if (dataIn == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for Data struct\n");
        return;
    }
    dataIn->kode = kode;
    strcpy(dataIn->variety, variety);
    dataIn->weight = weight;
    dataIn->date = date;
    
    if (headIn == NULL || headIn->date > date) {
        // insert node at the head
        dataIn->next = headIn;
        headIn = dataIn;
    } else {
        // insert node in the list
        struct Data *np = head;
        while (np->next && np->next->date >= date) {
            np = np->next;
        }
        dataIn->next = np->next;
        np->next = dataIn;
    }
}
```

Comment: So i changed my insert function to this, and then what do i do? is this function already include sorting? if not, how do i do the sorting? sorry if i'm asking too much

Comment: @EvelioExcellenta: this `insert` function does the sorting: it inserts the new node in the right place to keep the list sorted by increasing dates.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem for sorting this program

first i add a new struct

```html
struct node{
    int kode;           
    char variety[20];   
    int weight;             
    int date;       
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* newNode(int data){
  struct node* node = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  node->date  = data;
  node->left  = NULL;
  node->right = NULL;
   
  return(node);
}
```

and then i initiate an array

```html
struct Data order[100];
int k=0;
```

and then make the sorting functions

```html
struct node* insertSort(struct node* node, int data)
{
  if (node == NULL)
    return(newNode(data)); 
  else
  {
    if (data <= node->date)
        node->left  = insertSort(node->left, data);
    else
        node->right = insertSort(node->right, data);
    return node;
  }
}   

void sort(struct node* node) {
  struct node* current = node;
  if (node != NULL) {
    sort (current->left);
    order[k++].date =node->date ; 
    sort (current->right);
  }
}
```

and then i update my printing process so that it can print the sorted products

```html
void printList(struct Data *tempIn) {
    system ("cls");
    tempIn = headIn;
  
    
    int angka =0;
    struct node* root = NULL;
    while(tempIn!=NULL){
    
        if(root==NULL){
            root = insertSort(root, tempIn->date);
        }
        else {
            insertSort(root, tempIn->date);
        }
        tempIn = tempIn->next;
    }

    tempIn = headIn;
    
    printf("*****  DATA PRODUCT ***** \n" );
    printf("|  DATE  |  CODE  |      NAME      |  WEIGHT | \n");
    
    
    k=0;
    for (int i=0;i<100;i++){
        order[i].date=0;
        order[i].kode =0;
        order[i].weight=0;
    }
    sort(root);

    tempIn = headIn;
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
    tempIn = headIn;    
    while (tempIn != NULL) {
        if(order[i].date==tempIn->date){
        printf("    %d        %d     %-10s          %d        \n", tempIn->date, tempIn->kode, tempIn->variety, tempIn->weight);
        }
        tempIn = tempIn->next;
    }
}
    getch();
}
```